# Implement Google Adiantum else where?

Tags: implementation, cryptographic-hardware

Google made the headlines with its new Adiantum encryption method, and [i read](https://techcrunch.com/2019/02/07/google-makes-it-easier-for-cheap-phones-and-smart-devices-to-encrypt-your-data/) (TechCrunch) that:

> In the meantime don’t expect any instant gains, but future low-power
>   devices may offer better security without having to use more expensive
>   components — you won’t have to do a thing, either.

So mobile phone which does not have any hardware dedicated to crypto will still be able to encryption as perhaps an equal speed.

My question: can we use this technology in some other places which does not have such hardware? does it makes sense? (e.g in a web browser, having an implementation in WASM of Adiantum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that Adiantum was designed for one particular use case: block-based disk encryption.

In other contexts, especially in a web browser context, storing an IV and an authentication tag along with the ciphertext is not a problem. So you can stick to traditional AEADs, that will be faster than Adiantum in addition to being easier to use securely.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i wanted to read, it's hard for a beginner to get my bearings